# Positive semi-definiteness of a matrix whose diagonal elements slightly differ from the sum of the absolute values of other elements in the row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix which has the following form:

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b-\varepsilon_1 & -a & -b \\
-a & a+c-\varepsilon_2 & -c \\
-b & -c & b+c-\varepsilon_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where a, b, c, $\varepsilon_1$, $\varepsilon_2$ and $\varepsilon_3$ are all positive real numbers.

In other words, diagonal elements differ from the sum of the absolute values of other elements in the row (or column since the matrix is symmetric) by some epsilons ($\varepsilon_1$, $\varepsilon_2$, $\varepsilon_3$). If all the epsilons are zero, then according to [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), my matrix is positive semidefinite. However, if epsilons are not zero but small positive values instead, can my matrix still be positive semidefinite. How can I determine a bound for epsilons with respect to other elements of the matrix? I gave 3x3 matrix as an example, but my question is more general. The matrix can be extended a higher dimensional one.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about $a,b,c$? Positive?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: BTW you can type $\varepsilon_1$ like this: `$\varepsilon_1$`. For some basic information about writing math symbols at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, user 1551 is right. A better question would be: if $A$ is symmetric $\geq 0$ , how to choose $\Delta$ symmetric $\geq 0$ in order to obtain $A-\Delta\geq 0$ ?

A sufficient condition is $\sup(spectrum(\Delta))\leq \inf(spectrum(A))$.

Answer (score 3):

No. If at least one epsilon is positive, $A$ is never positive semidefinite. This is because when $e$ is the all-one vector, we have $e^TAe=-\sum\varepsilon_i<0$.